# Getting a huge list of files in ruby

Tags: ruby, enumeration

I'm trying do some operations on a directory which contains nearly 20 million files, I tried `Dir.glob`, `Dir.foreach` and `Dir.entries` to no success.
Is there anything similar to Csharp's `Directory.EnumerateFiles` in ruby which can enumerate a huge list of files?

Comment: _"... to no success"_ – please be more specific. What happens and how do you use these methods? (i.e. show some code)

Answer (score 0):

[Dir#read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-i-read) might do the trick.

```
dir = Dir.new(path)
while entry = dir.read
  puts entry
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But sadly it didn't do it either. Like other ones I tested, just hangs for a veeery long time and nothing happens.

Comment: @JeremyMc  it's probably working just taking a long time. isn't it printing the entry for you?

Comment: @Tiago No, It doesn't print anything at all.